# Smalltalk, increment a value from a dictionary of counters

Tags: dictionary, smalltalk

im working on Smalltalk, i have "tweets" collection, each tweet have "user" and i want to count the tweets by user in a dictionary.

So i have to add a counter in each key of the dictionary, and have to add keys for the first time i get the user.

I was thinking in this code for the add, i want to know if is human redeable and efficient or is there a better way to do it

```
tweetCountUserFrom: tweet in: aDictionary
    | user |
    user := tweet user.
    aDictionary at: user ifAbsentPut: 0.
    aDictionary at: user put: (result at: user) + 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is clear enough (even though it likely includes a mistake as the `result` variable should have been `aDictionary` instead). Anyway, the intention is clear and does (or is expected to do) the same a well-known object does, which is `Bag`. So, let's see how the code would have been with an instance of `Bag` (it is always a good idea to become increasingly familiar with the `Collection` hierarchy of Smalltalk). Here is how you could arrive at the same result

```
tweetCountUserFrom: tweet in: aBag
  aBag add: tweet user
```

That's it!

When it is time for you to see how many `tweets` a `user` has authored, you will only need to evaluate

```
 aBag occurrencesOf: user
```

Internally, `aBag` will hold a `Dictionary` and will maintain it the way you intended in your code. However, by using an existing object you will keep your code simpler, shorter and easier to read and maintain. You will also decrease the probability of failure as `Bags` have been kicking around for more than 40 years now, so there is little chance for them to decieve you.

Comment: Well said!  I would not write it better.